# Customized Listview (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, listview, controls

I'm trying to make a listview that looks something like this:

[image]

Edited: The listview has a custom header, the selected column is highlighted in another color, columns can be resized, customizable slider, anything else is visible in the picture.

Is it realistic to make such control using VB.NET? If so where would you recommend starting? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip: you'll probably see better answers if you explain specific features you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The image you showed looks more like a DataGrid to me than a list view and if you are willing to spend money there are a lot of third party products you can use, like ComponentArt  http://www.componentart.com/

Edited Answer:

Just use a DataGridView .  I'm pretty sure all the elements can be styled the way you want.

If this is for a webpage then you can just build a table using html and css.

Comment: I think your only realistic approach is to use the DataGridView control that comes with .net and play around with styling, or build a table in html if this is for a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible... but is definitely not easy (at least for me).

I'm doing around with a custom listview (added some functionality and new properties) by myself but have no experience with custom drawing. What i know is, that you have to do a complete custom drawing for a result like in the picture.
I tried custom drawing once because i wanted alternating line background colors, custom grid-lines and -color and also a custom highlight color but gave up for now because i had proplems with displaying checkboxes (the display style of them) in the lines and deceided that i use the default style for now in my app.
I got the alternating background for the rows working due to a different approach (firing custom event using a modified ListViewItemCollection) but still want to have a custom grid one day.

I never used a DataGridView so far so I can't say anything about that but I think that it should be possible to extend a listview to do what you want (depending on the needed functionality).

A good starting point should be to just inherit a listview, set it to OwnerDraw and play around with the related events (OnDrawColumnHeader, OnDrawSubItem, OnDrawItem).

You can also take a look at "[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)", an Open-Source Project with a VERY extended Listview. I wasn't able to get it running because i use VB-Net Express.